Running alert on the click of "convert order" button on quote form and still have the conversion execute
I want to have a simple JScript run that provides a simple alert to the end user and then have the regular form functionality continue to run if the user clicks OK.  I have created the webresource and added it to the CRM ribbon on the quote form tied to the "create order" button already on the form.
Getting the alert to run is working just fine ( as it is very basic code); however, I cannot seem to get the quote to convert into an order and it won't even display that dialog box that normally appears when you convert the quote to an order.
I am trying to avoid creating a plug in for this due to the environment having a lot of other customizations, cost of doing it, and the fact that it is an integrated environment where the creation of an order automatically goes into their ERP system.
Any ideas?  I know there are some unsupported ways to do this, but I am only interested in supported options.
Thank you in advance for any help or guidance you can provide.
I have tried creating a web resource that throws the alert. I have added that to the button functionality of the Create Order button. The alert throws, but it does not continue to run the regular functionality
I used Ribbon Workbench to modify the form buttons.
